# google drive scripting folder location

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a GApp which scratch builds a new GDrive spreadsheet.  I shows up in my  root directory.
I would like to place the new SS in a specific folder instead.

I cannot seem to find how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#addToFolder%28Folder%29)

```
// This example creates a new file and adds it to a folder
// Note: This can also be used on a folder to add it to another folder
var file = DocsList.createFile('my test file', 'test file contents');
var folder = DocsList.createFolder('My Test Folder');
file.addToFolder(folder);
Logger.log(file.getParents()[0].getName()); // logs 'My Test Folder'
```

Just a heads up, depending on how you create your spreadsheet you might have difficulties, `DocumentApp.create()` and `file` appear to be different object types. But no worries, `file` has its own create method (`DocsList.createFile(name, contents)`) which can be referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/)

Hope that helps.